# I am able to login with username and password manually(on browser) but not able to login through my batch job using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

```
HtmlPage signinPage = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("https://imeidb.gsma.com/imei/index");
System.out.println("signinPage -----------------------------------" + signinPage.getUrl());
HtmlForm form = signinPage.getFormByName("signIn");
HtmlTextInput loginField = (HtmlTextInput)form.getInputByName("username");

loginField.setValueAttribute(userName);

System.out.println("Username :"+loginField.toString());
HtmlPasswordInput pwdField = (HtmlPasswordInput)form.getInputByName("password");

pwdField.setValueAttribute(password);
System.out.println("Username :"+pwdField.toString());

HtmlButtonInput loginBtn = (HtmlButtonInput)signinPage.getHtmlElementById("loginImg");

System.out.println("HtmlButtonInput loginBtn -----------------------------------" + loginBtn.toString());
System.out.println("HtmlButtonInput loginBtn getHtmlElementById -----------------------------------" + signinPage.getHtmlElementById("loginImg"));
System.out.println("HtmlButtonInput signinPage getStatusCode -----------------------------------" + signinPage.getWebResponse().getStatusCode());
System.out.println("HtmlButtonInput signinPage getStatusMessage -----------------------------------" + signinPage.getWebResponse().getStatusMessage());

resultPage = (HtmlPage) loginBtn.click();
```

Comment: I assume there's also a question attached?

Comment: What is the question here? What is the error you get? What is the expected output, and what happenst instead?

Comment: Hi Ram, 
Are there any errors in resultPage.getOneHtmlElementByAttribute("div", "class", "errorSection errorsubsection")?

Comment: I am not able to find the error because i am trying to fetch the data from website which is held by third party.I think they are not able to validate because it is returning the same login url.

Comment: In resultpage it should give next page url but it is returning same login page url. I am not able to explain it properly.sorry for that but thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers for similar questions here.

Without having an account for that page i can't provide any details or any proved solutions. But anyway some hints:

- web page automation requires real knowledge of the basic web technologies
- make sure javascript is enabled for your webClient
- usually the pages are doing at least parts of there initialization based on javascript; because of this is a good idea to wait for the js after retrieving a page or forcing an action

  ```
  HtmlPage signinPage = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("https://imeidb.gsma.com/imei/index");
  webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);
  ```
- use the type method for filling entry fiels

  ```
  pwdField.type(password);
  ```
- the click() method returns the sync result page; in your case the button is no submit button; this usually indicates the page gets refreshed via javascript (async). Replace

  ```
  resultPage = (HtmlPage) loginBtn.click();
  ```

  by

  ```
  (HtmlPage) loginBtn.click();
  webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);

  resultPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
  ```

If this does not help, you can send me credentials for the page and i will try to help you with more details.

And finally - this works here. As a result i reach the 'Account Security Question' page like in real browsers.

```
    String url = "https://imeidb.gsma.com/imei/index";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {
        HtmlPage signinPage = webClient.getPage(url);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        // System.out.println("----------------");
        // System.out.println(signinPage.asXml());

        HtmlForm form = signinPage.getFormByName("signIn");
        HtmlTextInput loginField = (HtmlTextInput)form.getInputByName("username");
        loginField.type("xxxx");

        HtmlPasswordInput pwdField = (HtmlPasswordInput)form.getInputByName("password");
        pwdField.type("yyyy");

        HtmlButtonInput loginBtn = (HtmlButtonInput)signinPage.getHtmlElementById("loginImg");
        loginBtn.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        HtmlPage resultPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println(resultPage.asXml());
    }
```

Comment: Its not working it is returning the same login page url instead of next page url.

Comment: Thanks for your input but its not working.it is returning same login page url. Why?

Comment: Still its not working.It is returning the same page url.and if i mention this webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000); then it is giving timeout.

Comment: please use the latest snapshot build

Comment: ...Still its not working.Its giving org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: